# Degenerate Pi-notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

can i say that a degenerate productory like

$$
\prod_{t=1}^{0} (1+r_t)
$$

is equal to one? I cant seem to find a precise answer about this anywhere.

Comment: We call this an [Empty Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product), and is indeed defined to be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes – if you don't multiply by anything at all, it's the same as if you had multiplied by $1.$ That's why $x^0=1$ and why $0!=1.$